# one line for loop with function and tuple arguments

Tags: python, function, arguments, tuples

I am very interested why i can't write a oneliner with as:

```
m=[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
f=lambda x,y:return x%y
f(*i) for i in m
```

but i had to expand the last line to

```
for i in m:
  f(*i)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try [f(*i) for i in m]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x for x in y` syntax is used in [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), set comprehensions, and  dictionary comprehensions in Python. It is not valid to use it without surrounding `()`, `[]`, or `{}`.

A more correct version would be

```
>>> m = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> f = lambda x,y: x % y # Note no return
>>> [f(*i) for i in m]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Or even better, the less verbose

```
>>> [x % y for x,y in ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you all the suggestions were very good but this is explained exactly what I have done incorrectly. Thank you for your help. much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

actually, you can:

```
>>> [x%y for x,y in [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]]
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: or use `[x%y for x,y in ((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))]` as we don't need the second list

Comment: Thank you that's very nice and simple

Answer (score 2):

Using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> m = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> f = lambda x: x[0] % x[1]  # No return statement in lambda.
>>> map(f, m)  # list(map(f, m)) in Python 3.x
[1, 3, 5]
```

---

You can use tuple parameter unpacking in `lambda` if you use Python 2.x, but [it's gone in Python 3.x](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/):

```
f = lambda (x, y): x % y
```